# setup.cfg: command 'develop' has no such option 'index'

Tags: python, python-3.6, setup.py

I am trying to setup a new project and for some reason I am getting the following error while running:

```
pip install -e .

Running setup.py develop for projectname
Complete output from command /home/user/envs/ProjectName/bin/python3.6 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/home/user/dev/ProjectName/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" develop --no-deps:
    running develop
    error: error in setup.cfg: command 'develop' has no such option 'index'
```

My setup.py is quite standard and I am able to run tests, build a wheel and install the wheel in a different environment. But still I would like to understand why the `develop` command isn't working?

Comment: Does your `setup.cfg` contain a `[develop]` section with an `index` option?  Setuptools seems to be telling you not to do that.

Comment: A [mcve] showing how to create the simplest possible project that triggers this bug would be a good place to start in making the question answerable.